# Make bound field in grid like HyperLinkField

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a nested gridview as shown below. I populate the gridview from a stored procedure and method in my DAL/BLL layers. This works fine and data is returned to my nested gridview as I expect.

What I'd like to do though, is have the boundfield (VisitTypeId) in my nested gridview as a hyperlink, so the user can click on it and be redirected to the related 'Visit' for the Patient (in other words, 'where ID={0} and VisitTypeId={0}').

I'm certain this must be possible, but can't find a way to do it. Can someone please help?

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPatients" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsPatients" OnRowDataBound="gvVisits_RowDataBound"  
    DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="interactTable" CellPadding="4" 
    AllowSorting="True" meta:resourcekey="gvPersonsResource1">
     <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="row"/>
        <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" />
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" />
        <asp:Boundfield DataField="DoB" HeaderText="DoB" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Visits">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvVisits" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="0" ShowHeader="false" >
                    <Columns>
                    <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientID" Visible="false" /> --%>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="VisitTypeID" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/AddEditPatient.aspx?ID={0}" HeaderText="Edit" Text="Edit"  />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

DAL:

```
Public Shared Function GetVisitType(PatientId As Integer) As DataSet
Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString)
        Using myCommand As New SqlCommand("SPGetVisitType", myConnection)
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientID", PatientId)

            myConnection.Open()
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            Using myAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
                myAdapter.Fill(ds)
                Return ds
            End Using
            myConnection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

End Function
```

BLL:

```
Public Shared Function GetVisitType(ByVal PatientId As Integer) As DataSet
Dim ds As DataSet = ScreeningTestDAL.Visit.GetVisitType(PatientId)
Return ds
End Function
```

Codebehind:

```
    Protected Sub gvVisits_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim gv As GridView = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("gvVisits"), GridView)
        Dim PatientId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells(1).Text)
        Dim ds1 As DataSet = ScreeningTestBLL.VisitManager.GetVisitType(PatientId)
        gv.DataSource = ds1
        gv.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```